# What is a common way to tell if an academic is "above average," or outstanding in their field? Is their h-index (Hirsh index) one of them?

Tags: professorship, bibliometrics, ranking, evaluation

If one claimed that a particular scholar was "above average" or "noted" in their field, is there any good metric by which to support or deny such a claim?

Is there a generally accepted way to indicate that a particular professor or scholar is outstanding, or above average, in their field? I understand there are certain indicators, such as chairs, endowments, prizes, etc. But these don't really seem to help to compare one scholar to another, except in a sort of gross, simple count way (i.e. one professor has had more chairs than another)

Is it theoretically possible to create a "ranking" of professors in their fields, by some metric? Could their [h-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index) serve as such a metric?

Comment: Answers in comments and general advice has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93330/discussion-on-question-by-user151841-what-is-a-common-way-to-tell-if-an-academic). Please read [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230/7734) before posting another comment.

Answer (score 73):

**Yes, there is one and only one standard method** that is universally employed by reputable academic institutions worldwide.  This is how you evaluate a researcher:

1. **Read their papers.**
2. **Attend one of their talks.**
3. **Ask the opinion of other experts in the field.**

This is how hiring committees and promotion committees do their job.  There are no shortcuts.  Parts 1-2 require that you have some relevant expertise; if not then you must rely entirely on #3.

Every academic is regularly asked to give an expert opinion through reference letters, which often are expected to include some sort of ranking (e.g. *"Assistant Prof. X should be promoted because she is clearly as talented/better than Prof. Y who was recently promoted at Prestigious University Z"*).  How does one justify this kind of claim in the reference letter?  You guessed it:

1. Read their papers.
2. Attend their talks.

Comment: Well, this is perhaps how committees and panels should work, but definitely not how *every* hiring committee works in practice.

Comment: While I certainly agree with this for things like hiring and promotion, there are other instances where faculty are asked to evaluate other faculty where they may not be able/expected to solicit expert opinions (e.g., annual faculty evaluations, certain prizes, etc).

Comment: @David Ketcheson The method you propose is not fool-proof. What if there is a cabal of researchers who dismiss contrary opinions because they have a lot at stake? Happens a lot in fields like economics and social sciences that make unfalsifiable claims or else simply use fake statistics to "empirically prove" their hypothesis. If you are a researcher that publishes works that go against established dogma you are unlikely to be given good references.

Comment: @Tryer Well, that's what points 1 and 2 are there for. If the researcher in question is right, but neither you nor their colleagues can tell, I don't think there's any rating available that will do that job for you.

Comment: @sgf People who have unorthodox ideas very rarely get to publish or get invited to talks. This happens more in fields like the social sciences and history and economics where the people make unfalsifiable claims. How many orthodox economics departments invite for talks folks like Nassim Nicholas Taleb, for instance. The guy has a good set of arguments that when taken to their logical extreme would lead to dismantling finance and economics departments in universities. Which "respected" journal would publish his work and which university will invite him for talks?

Comment: @Tryer Which is why you have to read his stuff and come up with an opinion on them yourself. Which sort of metric could you imagine that would help there, short of making everything a popularity contest? There's no metric that will allow you to extract truth from papers.

Comment: Please note that when the person judging has no subject matter expertise - and thus has to resort to point 3 only - he is basically averaging subjective rankings (the typical letter starts or ends with “candidate XXXX ranks in the top 5/3/1% in her field”). Given the small amount of data and the inherent letter bias (I am not going to ask a letter to people who thinks of me less than outstanding) point 3 amounts to a quite poor ranking algorithm. This is where objective metrics come handy. Also, students can’t afford the luxury of choosing supervisors asking recommendation letters.

Comment: @famargar But choosing a supervisor based on how good/productive/famous they are _as a researcher_ is kind of stupid. The right question to ask is how successful they’ve been (or are likely to be) _as a supervisor_. And no, those are not the same thing.

Comment: @JeffE fully agree - in fact, I never said that. If you were to read my answer, you would actually see that I count academic success of students as an important parameter of the ranking algorithm. Would a score that is broken into supervising score, research score, and others subareas suit your case? This is similar to the ranking I have been assigned as an instructor to my institution (see a previous comment of mine).

Comment: **Absolutely not!**  Every student has their own career goals and their own advising needs.  A student who needs/prefers close supervision should not prefer an advisor who gives his students free reign.  A student who is aiming for industry research positions should not prefer an advisor whose students all either stay in academia or work as code monkeys at Twitter.  A student who wants to study complexity theory should not choose an advisor that specializes in computational geometry. And so on.  Choosing the right advisor is a subtle, individual _judgement_ call; there is no algorithm.

Comment: @JeffE your earlier comment seems to say that the problem was in subdividing reputation in "research reputation" and "reputation as supervisor", hence my answer. Here instead I see a bigger problem: you are saying that the world would NOT be a better place if someone gave young aspiring academics a tool to support their choise of a supervisor among the 99% of professors who self-proclaim to be in the best 5% in their field. This is *exactly* where an objective metric would be the most helpful, as the people making a decision are the ones with the least information at hand to do so.

Comment: @farargar I'm not objecting to tools.  I'm objecting to the suggestion of using a single simple tool to make subtle, subjective, and individualistic decisions. Would you consider a similar "objective" metric suitable for choosing a city to live in, or a house to buy, or a partner to marry? (Also: I know *very* few professors who proclaim themselves to be "in the best 5% in their field"; your 99% claim is nonsense. To first approximation, anyone who makes such a claim about themselves is wrong.)

Comment: @JeffE I am advocating for using a metric, not a simple metric - please see my answer below. And yes, there are plenty of available metrics these days which are great for choosing a city or a neighborhood or a car. Again, the problem is not if a good metric can be built - of course it can - but where such a metric would be useful. And the answer is to determine decision making when other information is absent, or to support it when subject matter expertise is available

Comment: @JeffE as for marriage, it is a great example of where human fallacies lead to wrong decision making - approximately 50% of the times, indeed

Comment: _I am advocating for using a metric, not a simple metric_ — Yes, you are. Any metric that provides only a single number is simple. (And in case you missed my point: People generally buy cars only after driving them.)

Comment: @JeffE I deduce that you are not familiar with statistics. A ranking algorithm is indeed a number. A “simple number” as you say. That simple number would be the result of a regression model that can use a large number of inputs (numerical and/or categorical) and can combine them in an arbitrarily complex fashion (from linear regression to deep neural networks). Not that simple, as you see

Comment: As for cars, people buy them after asking around, reading at experts review, look at average of customer reviews, gas mileage, price, brand, drive satisfaction. All mental parameters that are combined in a mental regression model whose outcome is “I like car A more than car B and less than car C”. But as we are all different, for cars (and for professors too) we may decide to just look at all the inputs objectively and then combine them arbitrarily.

Answer (score 26):

> If one claimed that a particular scholar was "above average" or "noted" in their field, is there any good metric by which to support or deny such a claim?

No. As a rule of thumb, this isn't the kind of thing that you can measure with a metric. Elvis Presley was the king of rock and roll. Why? Is it because he pumped out more albums than the others? Because he sold more? Because journalists wrote more about his albums than the others'? No. It was because he was the king and few people contested that. It's the same in academia. Either you can say that someone is "noted" in the field and be reasonably confident that you won't be contested when saying that, or you can't. If you can't, then you should avoid it, on pain of looking pretentious or like a toady.

> Is there a generally accepted way to indicate that a particular professor or scholar is outstanding, or above average, in their field? I understand there are certain indicators, such as chairs, endowments, prizes, etc. But these don't really seem to help to compare one scholar to another, except in a sort of gross, simple count way (i.e. one professor has had more chairs than another)

In general, you can't compare people. This isn't a video game, people don't have a numeric level associated to their academic ability, someone with a 12 being better than someone with a 5. It doesn't work like that. There is a multitude of factors, most often not measurable or not comparable. Trying to make a sum out of these and comparing the result for two different people will only lead to crap. Ask any hiring committee if determining who is the best candidate for a job is easy, let alone determining who is the best researcher.

> Is it theoretically possible to create a "ranking" of professors in their fields, by some metric? Could their h-index serve as such a metric?

God no. Of all the metrics, you've probably picked one of the worse ones. If I write two dozens pieces of trash that all cite one another and publish them in vanity press, I will have a great h-index. Will I be a good researcher? No. On the other hand, if I write a single article in my whole life solving the Riemann hypothesis, then I would probably become one of the most famous mathematician in the world overnight, but my h-index will be crap.

Comment: Could you suggest a metric which is better than h-index?

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov Why would you want any metric _at all_?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93353/discussion-on-answer-by-user108384-what-is-a-common-way-to-tell-if-an-academic-i).

Answer (score 10):

If you want to rank two professors against each other, you might be tempted to use the h-index. Don't. As many of the other answers point out, it's a severely flawed metric, and it doesn't really tell you a lot.

However, if you want to figure out whether a given professor can reasonably be described as "noted" or "outstanding", then that is a quite different question. And here, yes indeed, I would say that you can use certain indicators, namely awards, honors and prizes. I do not think anyone disputes that a scientist holding a Nobel prize is outstanding. (Peace and literature, maybe not so much.) If a mathematician wins the Fields medal or the Abel prize, the same.

Many societies award fellowships. To get one of those, you have to demonstrate academic excellence, and often also things like service to the society in question, outreach, teaching etc. The advantage is that the "overall package" a professor offers has already been evaluated by people who are presumably experts in the field. For instance, [here is a list of the Fellows of the International Institute of Forecasters](https://forecasters.org/about/fellows/), which I happen to be involved with. Some of the Fellows are a bit contentious, but nobody from the field would dispute their being *noted*.

Best paper awards are similar.

Of course, you need to use a little expertise in deciding whether a Best Paper Award from a journal on Beall's list is truly a mark of excellence, or whether a Fellowship from an academic society that offers little more than a one-page webpresence is. But unless you go with the extremely well-known marks of excellence like the prizes I noted above, there is simply no shortcut that will avoid having at least a passing knowledge of the field.

And note that this allows you to decide whether someone is distinguished or not. It won't tell you whether A is "more distinguished" than B, like one might try to use the h-index to indicate. Which, as I argue above, is impossible.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a generally accepted way to indicate that a particular professor or scholar is outstanding, or above average, in their field?

The generally accepted method for assessing a particular scholar's merit is to familiarize oneself with their work. Such an assessment requires a solid basis of expert knowledge.

> I understand there are certain indicators, such as chairs, endowments, prizes, etc. But these don't really seem to help to compare one scholar to another, except in a sort of gross, simple count way.

This applies to any "metric", although some are worse than others. Any sound assessment would have to be *qualitative* and require some *substantive* engagement with the scholar's work. Therefore, any comparison, to the extent that it would be useful at all, could only point out qualitative differences that don't lend themselves to a ranking, "except in a sort of gross" way.

Comment: Qualitative differences DO lend themselves to a ranking, just as much as quantitative differences: “condition XXXX increases by YY.Y% the likelihood of a patient to develop disease ZZZZZ within K years”. Condition XXX can be quantitative (age, number of alcohol units per week, etc) or qualitative (sex, existence of other diseases). They are equally good to build a ranking and qualitative variables may very well be more important than then the quantitative ones.

Answer (score 3):

The negative proof to the question here is far broader than academics: is there a metric for the best car? Best parent? Best programming language? Smartest person? No, because all these things have many orthogonal dimensions that simply can't be collapsed to one without unacceptable information loss. Researchers can be creative, well funded, methodical, hard working, well versed in literature, collaborative with peers/students, etc.

I concur with David Ketcheson's answer on what to do instead.

Comment: Your comment assumes that no multidimensional problem can be analytically quantified. However, this comment comes a decade after machine learning and artificial intelligence (in english: algorithms solving complex multidimensional problems) became pervasive in our society. And a few decades after the mathematical/statistical groundwork to do so were born.

Comment: It also misses important contributions to psychology and behavioural economics that proved when and how humans take wrong decisions (hint: all the time ;)

Answer (score 2):

**All metrics** that used (e.g. number of first/senior authorships, sum of impact factors, percentile ranks of impact factors, citations, H-index, grants and other funding etc) have all their **advantages and many more disadvantages**. Never the less they are used in hiring processes in one or the other way because otherwise it is not possible to assess several hundred candidates that apply for a faculty position. Which of these factors are important in a certain sub-field is very different. Only the ones scoring top in these metrics will make it to the interview where then other factors might count as well.

For someone who is not familiar with a certain field the **easiest** (but still not always correct) **way** to see how good a professor might be is the **name of the university**. e.g. a professor at Cambridge will most likely have achieved a lot in his life. Someone at a no-name place will not have made much impact that impressed other people in the same field and if such a person does make a big impact one day then he will most likely get offers to move to a place with a better name.

Answer (score 1):

> If one claimed that a particular scholar was "above average" or
>   "noted" in their field, is there any good metric by which to support
>   or deny such a claim?

The only "generally approved" quantitative metric is the h-index. H-index is a metric, is OKfor your task as it allows you to define above or below average. As a matter of fact, this is the way some national educations systems stamp their professors as good enough for tenure. It is also agreed that it is not "good enough" - famously, Peter Higgs, 2013 Nobel in Physics, would fail miserably a ranking based on h-index only, as he published very few paper, although with huge citation count. Also, h-index is a measure of lifetime achievements, thus needs to be corrected for the academic age. Which brings us to the next point.

> Is there a generally accepted way to indicate that a particular
>   professor or scholar is outstanding, or above average, in their field?
>   I understand there are certain indicators, such as chairs, endowments,
>   prizes, etc. But these don't really seem to help to compare one
>   scholar to another, except in a sort of gross, simple count way (i.e.
>   one professor has had more chairs than another)

Other, mostly qualitative metrics are regularly used, consciously or not, in academic's minds, although no official ranking exist. I will mention a few, the ordering only reflecting the stage in an academic career:

```
1. Institution where PhD has been obtained
2. PhD supervisor
3. national prizes 
4. national grants
5. number of PhD students supervised
6. chairs at institutions or conferences
6. international prizes
7. academic success of PhD students mentored
8. more I could not think about now :)
```

> Is it theoretically possible to create a "ranking" of professors in
>   their fields, by some metric?

Of course it is, there is entire field about it called Scientometrics. You have to 1) fix for h-index known limitations 2) combine with the variables above to come up with a more comprehensive algorithm that will rank any researcher in any field. The reasons why this has not been done before are twofold. First, it is not easy at all to define objectively how much every metric listed here should weight in the ranking algorithm. Second, and most importantly, academics rank every day for jobs, promotions, accepting papers or conference contributions, prizes etc. However, they prefer their ranking algorithm to suit their individual minds, rather than adopting a common framework.

> Could their h-index serve as such a metric?

As described above, h-index has many limitations that make it impractical for most purposes. But an entire field of research exists around it - [Scientometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientometrics) - so rest assured there will be developments.

Comment: I disagree with many of the things you say: h-index is not a good metric because it led to more or less submersed citation rings to artificially boost that metric and get promotions. Second, "academics like to rank": who said that? Most of the academics I know are certainly not interested in ranking anyone.

Comment: Academics rank all the time other academics for a job, a promotion, a prize. However, they don't like to use commonly shared algorithms for doing that.I will specify that. H-index is good in the sense that is well-defined, sensible and allows comparisons. It is not a comprehensive metric however, as I specifically write.

Comment: The fact that they _have_ to rank for certain specific purposes doesn't mean that they _like_ to rank. Furthermore, as I said, the h-index brought several distortions in scientific publishing and that's definitely _not good_.

Comment: Thanks. I did edit the answer integrating your inputs. I think I made clearly enough that h-index is not good enough. As for the bias induced by ranking, this applies to any ranking, explicit or not. See the fact that most of US professors come from Ivy League schools - nobody attached points to it, however most committees do take that into accout.

Comment: Since academics rank each other all the time for jobs, promotions, prizes, etc. do they use the H-index as the whole or as a part of that ranking calculation?

Comment: @user151841 when h-index is used, it is normally used as part of a hiring/promotion selection. I have never been in a prize committee, but I suspect h-index rarely or never matter there - the reason being that a single, monumental scientific contribution will basically not alter your h-index, but will alter history (again, Petet Higgs and the 2013 physics Nobel prize being an example)